# Ktlint vs Detekt - List of differences

Tags: kotlin, lint, static-code-analysis, detekt

I searched many websites but I didn't find any compare Ktlint vs Detekt. I need to know the differences, not the common features. I want choose one but I won't test them myself. Someone can give me few differences?

Comment: basically this is off-topic here; but ktlint is on formatting, whereas detekt is about code analysis (code complexity, code smells, like too many functions in class etc). You can configure detekt to integrate ktlint, but I prefer to have it as separate tasks